# using a mongo script from inside the javascript shell?

Tags: shell, mongodb

I know how to run a mongodb script from the command line and then enter the shell.  E.g.,

> mongo --shell dbname dbnameinit.js

But once I'm inside the shell, can I execute another script?  Anything like db.dbname.load("anotherscript.js")???

Thanks!
-- ge

Answer (score 9):

Use: `load("anotherscript.js")`

Comment: Yep, it worked.  Weird - I **swear** I tried that before.  Thanks for getting me to try it again, yi_H!!